# real time chat in laravel and vue js using pusher?

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, real-time, pusher, pusher-js

Hi everyone please guide me how can i use pusher in real time chat system . pusher is installed in my app and working for real time notification but i want to add pusher in my messages . My message system is working fine . Please add pusher code here .  if it need broadcasting event or notification u can tell me bcz i have concept of that . what should i add in event etc . but i have no concept of pusher . 
This is vue js file code .

```
`data:{ msg: 'my new msg', content: '', privsteMsgs: [], singleMsgs:[], msgFrom: '', conID: '', friend_id: '', seen: false, newMsgFrom: ''`

ready: function(){
    this.created();

},
created(){
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/getMessages')
        .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data); // show if success
    app.privsteMsgs = response.data; //we are putting data into our posts array
})
.catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error); // run if we have error
    });
},
methods:{
    message: function(id){
       // alert(id);

        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/getMessages' +id)
            .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data); // show if success
        app.singleMsgs = response.data;
        app.conID = response.data[0].conversation_id;
    })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error); // run if we have error
        });

    },

    inputHandler(e){
        if(e.keyCode===13 && !e.shiftKey){
            e.preventDefault();
            this.sendMsg();
        }
    },
    sendMsg(){
        if(this.msgFrom){
          //  alert(this.conID);
           // alert(this.msgFrom);

            axios.post('http://localhost:8000/sendMessage', {
                conID: this.conID,
                msg: this.msgFrom
            })

                .then( (response) => {
              //  console.log('save Successfully');
                console.log(response.data); // show if success



            if(response.status===200){
                console.log('save Successfully')
               // console.log('save Successfully'+ data);
                 app.singleMsgs = response.data;
                app.msgFrom= '';

              // /  app.conID = response.data[0].conversation_id;
            }

        })
        .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error); // run if we have error
            });


        }
    },
    friendID: function(id){
        app.friend_id = id;
    },
    sendNewMsg(){
        axios.post('http://localhost:8000/sendNewMessage', {
            friend_id: this.friend_id,
            msg: this.newMsgFrom,
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data); // show if success
                if(response.status===200){
                    window.location.replace('http://localhost:8000/messages');
                    app.msg = 'your message has been sent successfully';
                }

            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error); // run if we have error
            });
    }



}
```

These are the Routes

```
Route::get('/messages', function () {
return view('messages');
```

});
Route::get('/getMessages', function () {

```
$allUsers1 = DB::table('users')
    ->Join('conversations','users.id','conversations.user_one')
    ->where('conversations.user_two', Auth::user()->id)->get();


$allUsers2 = DB::table('users')
    ->Join('conversations','users.id','conversations.user_two')
    ->where('conversations.user_one', Auth::user()->id)->get();
return array_merge($allUsers1->toArray(), $allUsers2->toArray());
```

});
Route::get('/getMessages{id}', function ($id) {

```
$userMsg = DB::table('messages')
    ->where('conversation_id', $id)->get();
// echo $userMsg;
return $userMsg;
```

});
Route::post('/sendMessage','MessagesController@sendMessage');

Route::get('newMessage/{id}','MessagesController@newMessage');
Route::post('sendNewMessage', 'MessagesController@sendNewMessage');

And these are the controller functions

```
public function sendMessage(Request $request){

    $conID= $request->conID;
     $msg= $request->msg;


    $checkUserId = DB::table('messages')->where('conversation_id', $conID)->get();
    if($checkUserId[0]->user_from== Auth::user()->id){
        // fetch user_to
        $fetch_userTo = DB::table('messages')->where('conversation_id', $conID)
            ->get();
        $userTo = $fetch_userTo[0]->user_to;
    }else{

        $fetch_userTo = DB::table('messages')->where('conversation_id', $conID)
            ->get();
        $userTo = $fetch_userTo[0]->user_to;
    }

    // now send message
    $sendM = DB::table('messages')->insert([
        'user_to' => $userTo,
        'user_from' => Auth::user()->id,
        'msg' => $msg,
        'status' => 1,
        'conversation_id' => $conID
    ]);
    if($sendM){
        $userMsg = DB::table('messages')
            ->join('users', 'users.id','messages.user_from')
            ->where('messages.conversation_id', $conID)->get();
        return $userMsg;
    }

}
public function newMessage($id){
    $uid = Auth::user()->id;

    $friend = DB::table('users')->where("id", "=", $id)->first();

    return view('newMessage', compact('friend'));




}
public function sendNewMessage(Request $request)
{
    $msg = $request->msg;
    $friend_id = $request->friend_id;

    $myID = Auth::user()->id;

    $checkCon1 = DB::table('conversations')->where('user_one',$myID)
        ->where('user_two',$friend_id)->get(); 
   $checkCon2 = DB::table('conversations')->where('user_two',$myID)
        ->where('user_one',$friend_id)->get();
    $allCons = array_merge($checkCon1->toArray(),$checkCon2->toArray());


    if(count($allCons)!=0){
        $conID = $allCons[0]->id;
        $MsgSent = DB::table('messages')->insert([
            'user_from' => $myID,
            'user_to' => $friend_id,
            'msg' => $msg,
            'conversation_id' =>  $conID,
            'status' => 1
        ]);


    }
    else{

        $con = new Conversation();
        $con->user_one = $myID;
        $con->user_two = $friend_id;


        $con->save();
        echo $con->id;

        $MsgSent = DB::table('messages')->insert([
            'user_from' => $myID,
            'user_to' => $friend_id,
            'msg' => $msg,
            'conversation_id' =>  $con->id,
            'status' => 1
        ]);


    }







}
```

Comment: Do you _have_ to use pusher? Firebase makes all this boilerplate cruft go away.

Answer (score 0):

/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import Vue from 'vue'
import VueChatScroll from 'vue-chat-scroll'
Vue.use(VueChatScroll)
//Loading component vuejs
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));
Vue.component('chatbox', require('./components/Chatbox.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
          msg: 'Click on user from left side:',
        getUserChat:'',
        privateMsgs: [],
        singleMsgs : [],
        msgFrom : '',
        conID: '',
        friend_id: '',
        seen1: false,
        seen: false,
        newMsgFrom: '',
        typing:'',
        BlackchaterUrl :'http://localhost:8000', 
    },
    watch:{
      msgFrom(){
          Echo.private('chat')
          .whisper('typing', {
           name: this.msgFrom,
           userid: this.getUserChat
          });
      }
    },
    ready: function()
    {
        this.created();
    },
    created()
    {
        axios.get(this.BlackchaterUrl + '/getMessages')
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);//show if success
            app.privateMsgs = response.data;//we are puting data in our post array
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);//show if get some error
          });
    },
    methods:
    {
        messages(id)
        {
           axios.get(this.BlackchaterUrl + '/getMessages/' + id)
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);//show if success
            app.singleMsgs = response.data;//we are puting data in our post array
            app.conID = response.data[0].conversation_id;
            app.getUserChat =response.data[0].user_from;
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);//show if get some error
          });
        },

```
    inputHandler(e)
    {
        if(e.keyCode ===13 && !e.shiftKey)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.sendMsg();
            this.msgFrom = "";
        }
    },
    sendMsgOld()
    {

        this.sendMsg();
        this.msgFrom = "";

    },
    sendMsg()
    {


        if(this.msgFrom.length != 0)
        {

          axios.post(this.BlackchaterUrl + '/SendMessage', {
            conID: this.conID,
            msg : this.msgFrom
          })
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);//show if success
            if(response.status===200)
            {
                app.singleMsgs = response.data;
            } 
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);//show if get some error
          });
        }
    },
    friendID: function(id)
    {
      app.friend_id = id;
    },
    inputHandler1(e)
    {
        if(e.keyCode ===13 && !e.shiftKey)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.sendNewMsg();
            this.msgFrom = "";
        }
    },
     sendNewMsg()
    {
            axios.post(this.BlackchaterUrl + '/sendNewMessage', {
            friend_id: this.friend_id,
            msg: this.newMsgFrom,
          })
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data); // show if success
            if(response.status===200){
              window.location.replace('http://localhost:8000/messages');
              app.msg = 'your message has been sent successfully';
            }

          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error); // run if we have error
          });
   }    
},
mounted()
{
   Echo.private('chat')
     .listen('ChatEvent', (e) => {
        document.getElementById('chatAudioNotif').play();
        this.singleMsgs.push(e);
     //console.log(e);
   })
    .listenForWhisper('typing', (e) => {
      if(e.name !='')
      {
        this.typing = 'typing .........'
      }
      else
      {
        this.typing = ''
      }

   });
}
```

});